# Canvas binding in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to create a canvas, with items located at specefied locations on the canvast, as i can not bind an source and a template directly to a Canvas, have i used a ItemsControl.
But there are a problem all the items are located at 0,0. And i have tested the Bindings they do not return 0,0.
How can i make this work so the items are located at the right place?

Also is it poissible to create 2 layers on the canvas, where each layer is binded to a diffrent source, and uses a diffrent template?

This is in Silverlight

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                Width="650" Height="650"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Skills}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Margin="0"
                Width="650" Height="650" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SkillPointsStatusText}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Test with ItemContainerStyle

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                Width="650" Height="650"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Skills}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Margin="0"
                Width="650" Height="650" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SkillPointsStatusText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Well i have droped the project, but i will leave the question open should one have an anwser

Comment: I added a bounty since i pretty much killed the question when you asked it with my non-working answer, sorry about that. Hopefully this will give it the attention it deserves.

Comment: Can you post the code for the classes that you're trying to bind to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*All of the following does not work in SL4 since it depends on bindings in a `Setter.Value`.*

---

Try setting the binding in the `ItemContainerStyle` since your `StackPanel` is not the root element; your template will be placed in a `ContentPresenter`, so your attached properties for canvas positioning in the `StackPanel` will be ignored.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

---

**Edit:** If Silverlight does not support `ItemContainerStyle` you can set the universal style for `ContentPresenters` which should work just as well:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Where are this <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> to be inserted? I keep getting Error "The attachable property 'ItemContainerStyle' was not found in type 'ItemsControl'".

Comment: It's not an attached property, you place it as a child of the ItemsControl the same way you use <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>. i.e. It does **not** belong inside the ItemTemplate.

Comment: See have i have inserted it in the first post, this give me the error,   Error 1 The property 'ItemContainerStyle' does not exist on the type 'ItemsControl' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: Oh, i have tested it in WPF and it works, could it be that this property simply does not exist in Silverlight? I added another way to do it without using that property.

Comment: Hmm this it now gives me a error "Cannot set read-only property ''." when i inset the <ItemsControl.Resources>. It does not seem to be the Resources itself but the 2 <Setter Property that is coursing the problem

Comment: Urgh, i give up... if both methods don't work i really don't know what do do.