# Assigning zIndex order to image and text elements on a canvas in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, z-index, frameworkelement

I have an image editor in silverlight that allows the user to add, manipulate and delete image and text elements on a canvas. I notice it seems to act strangely when adding new elements sometimes and they will be placed behind an existing element for example. Below is the code for adding image elements, and the order elements method which it calls. I inherited this code from someone else so at times I can't follow what his intention was. The code doesn't seem to do what it is supposed to though.

Can someone suggest a better way to assign a Z-Index value to elements that I am adding?

XAML of my workspace canvas -

```
<Canvas x:Name="pnlCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="{Binding Path=CanvasHeight, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                        Width="{Binding Path=CanvasWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" >
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements, Mode=OneWay}"  >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas Background="{Binding Path=CanvasBackground, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Height="{Binding Path=CanvasHeight, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                                    Width="{Binding Path=CanvasWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Canvas>
```

Adding image element -

```
private void AddImageElement(object param)
    {
        bool? gotImage;
        string fileName;
        BitmapImage imageSource = GetImageFromLocalMachine(out gotImage, out fileName);
        OrderElements();

        if (gotImage == true)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Name = fileName;
            image.Source = imageSource;
            image.Height = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.Width = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.MaxHeight = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.MaxWidth = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            image.Tag = null;



            AddDraggingBehavior(image);
            image.MouseLeftButtonUp += element_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            this.Elements.Add(image);
            numberOfElements++;

            this.SelectedElement = image;
            this.SelectedImageElement = image;
        }
    }
```

Order Elements -

```
private void OrderElements()
    {
        var elList = (from element in this.Elements
                      orderby element.GetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty)
                      select element).ToList<FrameworkElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < elList.Count; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = elList[i];
            fe.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, i);

        }

        this.Elements = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>(elList);

    }
```

My end intention once I have this sorted out is to include a layers container like in Photoshop etc. where I will be able to reorder the elements. Hopefully someone can help get me moving in that direction. Basically how do I set the Z-Index correctly because I don't think this is doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure if its related, but I had [a similar ZIndex issue with Dragging/Dropping items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2525030/302677), where re-assigning the ZIndex was changing the property, but not re-rendering the item at its new ZIndex. My end solution was to use the `Dispatcher` to make sure the ZIndex got set on a lower dispatcher priority than Render, although the problem went away once I switched to .Net 4.0

Comment: Looking at this now, does it even do anything? Debugging I see that the list has an extra element in it when I add an image. But does it actually assign a Z-index value to the elements?

Comment: How are your elements added to the UI? If you're using an `ItemsControl`, you need to set the `ZIndex` in the `ItemContainerStyle`, not on the actual UIElement, since an `ItemsControl` wraps each item in a `ContentPresenter`. I'd highly recommend taking a look at your application with something like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out if the ZIndex is set on the correct element

Comment: You mean to set it on the XAML? I've included the XAML of the canvas, they are held in ItemsControl but are added programatically, not in the XAML, if that makes any sense at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` wraps each element in a `<ContentPresenter>` tag, so although the ZIndex is set on your element, it doesn't get applied because the `ZIndex` on the `ContentPresenter` is what matters

What actually gets rendered looks like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Image Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" />
    </ContentPresenter>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

To fix the issue, set the `ZIndex` in the `ItemContainerStyle` so it gets applied to the `ContentPresenter` instead of the UI Element

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Canvas.ZIndex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For more information, see the bottom section of [my blog post about WPF's ItemsControl](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/)

**Edit:**

Apparently Silverlight doesn't have an `ItemsContainerStyle` for the `ItemsControl`.

In that case, simply set an implicit style for the `ContentPresenter` that sets the `Canvas.ZIndex` value in your `ItemsControl.Resources`

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Canvas.ZIndex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to add this to my XAML in the itemscontrol? Will I need to set my ZIndex elsewhere then or will each be set as they are added?

Comment: @Steve You would set this this in your XAML for the `ItemsControl` as the `ItemContainerStyle` property. It should bind the ContentPresenter's `Canvas.ZIndex` to your FrameworkELement's `Canvas.ZIndex`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be ItemContainerStyle on ItemsControl in Silverlight. I know it is in WPF. Back to square one?

Comment: @Steve Wow I never realized that property didn't exist in Silverlight! Try setting a universal style for `ContentPresenters` in `ItemsControl.Resources`. I've updated my answer with that information too.

Comment: Actually according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4771389/302677), you cannot set bindings in the `Setter.Value` as of SL4, so I'm not sure if the XAML I have posted will work. You may need to do something messy in the code-behind to set the ZIndex of the ContentPresenters when they get generated.